# Axios Error when checking for login credentials

Tags: http, post, axios

I am getting a bad request error when I am checking for the login credentials. The thing is when the credentials are correct I don't get any error but when the credentials are wrong or the user already exists the site breaks with a 400 bad request error (error in response is triggerred from the process error function in API call). Below is my code

**Handles the login at client side**

```
const loginUser = async (data) => {
    let response = await API.userLogin(data);
    if (response.isSuccess) {
      sessionStorage.setItem(
        "accessToken",
        `Bearer ${response.data.accessToken}`
      );
      sessionStorage.setItem(
        "refreshToken",
        `Bearer ${response.data.refreshToken}`
      );
      toast.success(response.data.msg, {
        position: "top-center",
        autoClose: 2000,
      });
      setName(response.data.name);
      setUserName(response.data.email);
      setAuthentication(true)
      navigate("/");
    } else {
      toast.error(response.msg, { position: "top-center", autoClose: 2000 });
      reset();
    }
  };
```

**Checks for login credentials**

```
export const loginUser = async (request, response) => {
  try {
    let user = await User.findOne({ email: request.body.email });
    if (!user) {
      return response.status(400).json({ msg: "User does not exist" });
    }
    let match = await bcrypt.compare(request.body.password, user.password);
    if (match) {
      const accessToken = jwt.sign(
        user.toJSON(),
        process.env.ACCESS_SECRET_KEY,
        { expiresIn: "15m" }
      );
      const refreshToken = jwt.sign(
        user.toJSON(),
        process.env.REFRESH_SECRET_KEY
      );
      const newToken = new Token({ token: refreshToken });
      await newToken.save();
      return response.status(200).json({
        accessToken: accessToken,
        refreshToken: refreshToken,
        msg: `Welcome back ${user.name}!`,
        name: user.name,
        email: user.email
      });
    } else {
      return response.status(404).json({ msg: "Wrong Credentials!!" });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return response.status(500).json({ msg: "Some error occurred!" });
  }
};
```

**API Call**

```
const processError = async (error) => {
  if (error.response) {
    console.log("Error in response ", error.toJSON());
    return {
      isError: true,
      msg: api_notification.responseFailure,
      code: error.response.status,
    };
  } else if (error.request) {
    console.log("Error in request ", error.toJSON());
    return {
      isError: true,
      msg: api_notification.requestFailure,
      code: "",
    };
  } else {
    console.log("Error in network ", error.toJSON());
    return {
      isError: true,
      msg: api_notification.networkError,
      code: "",
    };
  }
};

const API = {};

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(SERVICE_URLS)) {
  API[key] = (body, showUploadProgress, showDownloadProgress) =>
    axiosInstance({
      method: value.method,
      url: value.url,
      data: body,
      responseType: value.responseType,
      headers: {
        authorization: getAccessToken(),
        Accept: "application/json, multipart/form-data",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      onUploadProgress: function (progressEvent) {
        if (showUploadProgress) {
          let percentCompleted = Math.round(
            (progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total
          );
          showUploadProgress(percentCompleted);
        }
      },
      onDownloadProgress: function (progressEvent) {
        if (showDownloadProgress) {
          let percentCompleted = Math.round(
            (progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total
          );
          showDownloadProgress(percentCompleted);
        }
      },
    });
}
```

I tried removing the error handling part (process error function in API call). The error stays the same.